# Can we inject other commands between the time start is called on a thread and run actuals starts?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am studying for the OCP certification and I had to answer a question based on the snippet below.

The thing that confused me is, can we gurantee that the current thread is joining on `t`, before `t` has finished executing?

To me, `r1` `r2` `m1` `m2` seems a possible output.

What am I thinking in a wrong way?

```
class Infinity implements Runnable {

  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Infinity());
    t.start();
    System.out.println("m1 ");
    t.join();
    System.out.println("m2 ");
   }

   public void run() {
      System.out.println("r1 ");
      System.out.println("r2 ");
   }
}
```

Comment: To you really mean 'expected' or rather 'possible'?

Comment: You are right, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multithreading is never easy. This is because you have no guarantees when a specific part of your code will be started.

In this case, you have two threads: The main-thread "m" and the second thread "r".

First of all: The main-thread (*m*) will be started by executing your program.
Then it immediately spawns another thread (*r*) and starts it (`t.start()`).

Now you have two threads, running independently: *m* and *r*.
Unless you do not specify it they could be executed in any possible order, but - you specify it at some point with `t.join()`. Everything in the *m*-thread between `t.start()` and `t.join()` may be executed at any time during the *r*-thread. This might be the following order:
 - `m1 r1 r2`
 - `r1 m1 r2`
 - `r1 r2 m1`

Only m2 is restricted to wait for *r* to finish because of the `t.join()`.

So `r1 r2 m1 m2` is a possibly output, but it may also be `m1 r1 r2 m2` or `r1 m1 r2 m2`.

Comment: Addition: `t.join()` guarantees, `m2` is always at last.

Comment: Cool thats exactly I was thinking :)

Answer (score 4):

There are only three guarantees in this code:

- m1 happens before m2 (because they're in the same thread)
- r1 happens before r2 (because they're in the same thread)
- r2 happens before m2 (execution of the thread `t` is guaranteed to finish before `t.join()` can return)

Any ordering consistent with these three guarantees is possible.

```
m1 r1 r2 m2
r1 m1 r2 m2
r1 r2 m1 m2
```

If the print of m1 were before the call to `t.start()` rather than after it then that would introduce a fourth guarantee

- m1 happens before r1 (because actions in a thread always follow the starting of that thread)

which would mean only one possible execution trace

```
m1 r1 r2 m2
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it prints : `m1 r1 r2 m2` in must of cases because as soon as we started a thread we go on to do rest of the code and in this case it is print `m1`, but sometimes it may take a time an we switch between threads and in that cases we may get `r1 m1 r2 m2` or `r1 r2 m1 m2` like this two examples below:

This example is very likely to print `r1 r2 m1 m2` (but not 100%) because we have time to go on other thread when we see sleep(10) thread:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Infinity());
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(10);
    System.out.println("m1 ");
    t.join();
    System.out.println("m2 ");
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("r1 ");
    System.out.println("r2 ");
}
```

and This example is very likely to print `r1 m1 r2 m2` (but not 100%) and this because we have time to came back to main thread when we see sleep(100):

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Infinity());
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(10);
    System.out.println("m1 ");
    t.join();
    System.out.println("m2 ");
}

public void run() {
    System.out.println("r1 ");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("r2 ");
}
```

at the end I think it is obvious for you that `m2` printed last.

Comment: I understand the sleep thing, but how possible is the JVM to put a thread into sleep just after it hit started(or if you prefer, just before the first command of run), without having an explicit call to sleep?

Comment: @py_script Jvm didnt put it in sleep, JVM just continue running the main thread and didn't switch to the other thread.

Comment: The reason I am asking is to find out why it might not run print r1 first, in my example(without explicit sleep calls)